# Read zip files into Spark from MinIO

Tags: pyspark, zip

We have .zip files in MinIO/S3 bucket and would like read those files directly with PySpark/Spark APIs and write to Postgres SQL DB.

Read few articles which says .zip is not a valid file format for SPARK to read a file.

Tried reading zip file into Python pandas but getting memory issues, wanted to see if anyone has a solution to it.